# How to get config values by website or webstore in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

In Magento 1 it was possible to set/retrieve config values by website or store i.e

by website:

```
Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getConfig('settings/reference/prefix');
```

or via store

```
 Mage::app()->getStore()->getConfig('settings/reference/prefix');
```

However in magento 2 the config is set via the

```
Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig

$this->_scopeConfig->getValue('settings/reference/prefix')
```

My question now is, how can I retrieve the values by website/store?

Comment: have you checked my answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Here's how I do it in my helper:**

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    const MODULE_ENABLE = 'sectionName/groupName/fieldName';

    /**
     * @var ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig)
    {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    /**
     * Get store config value
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getConfigValue($field, $storeId = null)
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            $field,
            ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            $storeId
        );
    }

    /**
     * Check is enable
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function isEnable($storeId = null)
    {
        return $this->getConfigValue(self::MODULE_ENABLE, $storeId);
    }
}
```

**You can change the SCOPE_STORE to following:**

```
const SCOPE_STORES   = 'stores';
const SCOPE_GROUPS   = 'groups';
const SCOPE_WEBSITES = 'websites';
const SCOPE_GROUP   = 'group';
const SCOPE_WEBSITE = 'website';
```

Answer (score 5):

Just Use `\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig`, In your constructor argument and set the class property: `$this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;`

Now to Get the configuration value for Store or Website View use:

**Store View:**

```
$this->scopeConfig->getValue('settings/reference/prefix', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
```

**Website View:**

```
$this->scopeConfig->getValue('settings/reference/prefix', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITE);
```

Answer (score 1):

**In template (phtml) files, I use in the following way:**

```
$config = $block->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form::class);
$configValue = $config->getConfigValue('web/secure/base_url'); // website, store will be detected automatically
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->_scopeConfig->getValue('settings/reference/prefix', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITE); //Get value by Website

$this->_scopeConfig->getValue('settings/reference/prefix', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE); //Get value by store
```